# MFMailComposeViewController layout bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I use `UIActivityViewController` to share something in my project. When I choose email, a `MFMailComposeViewController` will be presented.  But something strange is navigation bar of this `MFMailComposeViewController` become `backgroundColor` transparent, and view of this VC has wrong layout. The view seems to ignore the existence of navigation bar. Is there anyone facing the same issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the photos displaying your issue?

Comment: @SachinVas Sorry I don’t have enough reputation to upload screenshot

Comment: add to image posting site and post the URL using website https://imgur.com

Comment: @Vinodh I upload image to my Twitter album(https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D0Up5LsUYAEbzFh.jpg)